# Mark All Mail Items As Read - Excluding Calendar Mail Items/Requests

Tags: vba, outlook

I have four macros that, when used together, will sweep through my inbox and all its subfolders and mark as read all the unread items excluding calendar type mail items.

This is inefficient since it goes through every mail item.

I had a different script where this wasn't an issue, but, it failed when it encountered a calendar type mail item.

I am looking for a way of combining the "search" criteria on the mail items to be marked as read.

Initially, the filter was done like this:

```
For Each item In strFolderPath.Items.Restrict("[unread] = true")

    item.UnRead = False

Next
```

As mentioned it errors on calendar type items and I am definitely doing my utmost to avoid `On Error Resume Next`.

The current way:

```
For Each objMailItem In currentFolder.Items
    
   If TypeName(objMailItem) <> "MeetingItem" And objMailItem.MessageClass <> "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request" Then
            
       objMailItem.UnRead = False
            
   End If
                
Next
```

It is tedious and long.

***CallAll***

```
Sub CallAll()

    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365890/find-underlying-object-type-for-outlook-meetingitem

    Dim InboxFolder As Folder
    Dim SubFolder As Folder
    Dim Folder As Folder
    Dim objInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    
    Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objInbox = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set InboxFolder = GetFolder(objInbox.FolderPath)
    
    For Each Folder In InboxFolder.Folders
        
        MarkAllRead (Folder.FolderPath)
        
    Next
    
    Set InboxFolder = Nothing
    Set Folder = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

***GetFolder***

```
Function GetFolder(strFolderPath As String) As MAPIFolder

    Dim colFolders As Outlook.Folders
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim arrFolders() As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    strFolderPath = Replace(strFolderPath, "\\", "")
    strFolderPath = Replace(strFolderPath, "/", "\")
    
    arrFolders() = Split(strFolderPath, "\")
    
    Set objFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders.item(arrFolders(0))
    
    If Not objFolder Is Nothing Then
    
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrFolders)
        
            Set colFolders = objFolder.Folders
            Set objFolder = Nothing
            Set objFolder = colFolders.item(arrFolders(i))
            
            If objFolder Is Nothing Then
            
                Exit For
                
            End If
            
        Next
        
    End If
    
    Set GetFolder = objFolder
    Set colFolders = Nothing
    
End Function
```

***GetSubFolder***

```
Function GetSubFolders(strFolderPath As String) As Long

    Dim WalkResultFolder As Folder
    Dim Folder As Folder
    Dim item As MailItem
    Dim WalkResult As Long
    
    Set WalkResultFolder = GetFolder(strFolderPath)
    
    For Each Folder In WalkResultFolder.Folders
    
        WalkResult = GetSubFolders(Folder.FolderPath)
    
        MarkAllRead (Folder.FolderPath)
        
    Next
    
    Set ResultFolder = Nothing
    Set Folder = Nothing
    Set item = Nothing
    
End Function
```

***MarkAllRead***

```
Function MarkAllRead(folderName As String)

    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365890/find-underlying-object-type-for-outlook-meetingitem

    Dim currentFolder As Folder
    Dim objMailItem As MailItem
    
    Set currentFolder = GetFolder(folderName)
    
    For Each objMailItem In currentFolder.Items
    
        Debug.Print "Folder Name: " & currentFolder
        Debug.Print "Mail Item: " & objMailItem
        
        If TypeName(objMailItem) <> "MeetingItem" And objMailItem.MessageClass <> "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request" Then
            
            objMailItem.UnRead = False
            
        End If
                
    Next
    
    For Each Folder In currentFolder.Folders
        
        MarkAllRead (Folder.FolderPath)
        
    Next
        
    Set WalkResult = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Function MarkAllRead(folderName As String)

    Dim SubFolder As Folder
    Dim currentFolder As Folder
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objUnreadItems As items
    
    Set currentFolder = GetFolder(folderName)
    Debug.Print "Folder Name: " & currentFolder
    
    Set objUnreadItems = currentFolder.items.Restrict("[Unread]=True")

    For Each objItem In objUnreadItems
        
        If TypeName(objItem) <> "MeetingItem" Then
            Debug.Print "Object Item: " & objItem.Subject
            If objItem.MessageClass <> "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request" Then
                objItem.UnRead = False
            End If
        End If
                
    Next
    
    For Each SubFolder In currentFolder.folders
        MarkAllRead (SubFolder.FolderPath)
    Next
        
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Sorry I took so long to reply.

This is brilliant, so thank you VERY much. I can't believe I just had to store an array FIRST of the unread items versus doing the check within the for loop..

There's an issue now though that it doesn't go through all the folders anymore.. Only goes through a few of them then stops and I need to rerun the macro.

But anyway, I will mark this as correct since you answered the original issue for me. Thank you! :)